# Input string was not in a correct format and Requiredfieldvalidator not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

So with the suggestions i updated my code.

## Textbox:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtStudent_Id" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
  ControlToValidate="txtStudent_Id"
  ErrorMessage="Id is required"
  ID="validator_ID"
  ValidationGroup="Validation_ID">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1"
          ControlToValidate="txtStudent_Id"
          ValidationExpression="\d+"
          Display="Static"
          EnableClientScript="true"
          ErrorMessage="Please enter numbers only" ValidationGroup="Validation_ID"
          runat="server"/>
```

### Button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmitStudent" ValidationGroup="Validation_ID" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnSubmitStudent_Click" />
```

### Code Behind:

```
addstudent.Student_Id =Convert.ToInt32(txtStudent_Id.Text);
```

Now that i have also entered the regular expression validator it should work but i still get the same error.

Comment: what you have declared student_id datatype in database

Comment: You need to validate integer number allowed and don't apply any special characters

Comment: The error is not related to validation etc, it must be appearing where you are converting text box value to integer, for validator to fire, your Button must have CasusesValidation property set to true

Comment: Where have you written this code "addstudent.Student_Id =Convert.ToInt32(txtStudent_Id.Text);"

Comment: Any one does not understand your question. All peoples have the solution for your error. but anyone does not say why the validation control not works? please see my answer for your solution.

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian I have declared it as an integer.

Comment: @TalalUrfQari check my answer. the problem is with the validation group you have to set the validation group for the requiredfieldvalidator control as well as in the submit button.

Comment: Can you post your current client side code with button?

Answer (score 1):

**Don't need a solution for your error.need a solution  why the validation control not works?**  and how can solve this problem?then what i do?

Main thing

> You have missed **ValidationGroup="XXXXX"** in *validation* control and *button* control, So it's allowed to server side code, so first add that and

try with this `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` for only allow integer value, So It's not allow if you  type any special and string characters

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStudent_Id" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="txtStudent_Id" ValidationGroup="XXXXX"    EnableClientScript="True"
     ErrorMessage="Id is required">
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1"
                   ControlToValidate="txtStudent_Id"
                   ValidationExpression="\d+"
                   Display="Static"
                   EnableClientScript="true"
                   ErrorMessage="Please enter numbers only" ValidationGroup="XXXXX"
                   runat="server"/>

<asp:button ValidationGroup="XXXXX"></asp:button>
```

or

```
 <asp:button ValidationGroup="XXXXX" CasusesValidation="true"></asp:button>
```

If you try my answer,then don't worry about *Input string was not in a correct format.* error.

**Update:**

please try this in your button click event.

```
Page.Validate();

if (Page.IsValid == false)
{

return;
}
```

//Call your code here

Comment: have you seen my answer buddy??

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian. If any one enter any string characters , Then the OP got a error. But your code goods for the validation works

Comment: @TalalUrfQari Can you post your current client side code with button?

Comment: @TalalUrfQari , did you try this button `<asp:button ValidationGroup="XXXXX" CasusesValidation="true"></asp:button>` instead of your code

Comment: @RameshRajendran, this is my submit button
**<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmitStudent" ValidationGroup="Validation_ID" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnSubmitStudent_Click" />**

Comment: And add `EnableClientScript="True"` in your validation control,then check

Answer (score 0):

**TextBox**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStudent_Id"
             runat="server"
             ValidationGroup="VAlidation_Name">
</asp:TextBox>
```

**RequiredFieldValidator**

you have not added id to the RequiredFieldValidator and also ValidationGroup

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server"  
                            Display="Dynamic" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtStudent_Id"
                            ID="rfvStudent_Id"
                            ForeColor="Red"
                            ValidationGroup="VAlidation_Name"
                            ErrorMessage="Id is required">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**Button Submit**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit"
            runat="server"
            ValidationGroup="VAlidation_Name" CausesValidation="true" />
```

In default `CausesValidation="true"` but check that too.

**Code Part**

```
addstudent.Student_Id =int.TryParse(txtStudent_Id.Text);
```

**Suggestion:**

And you can use AjaxToolKit Extender [MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) to make the user enter only integer.

```
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtEndDate_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" ClearTextOnInvalid="True"
                            ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true"  Enabled="True" Mask="9999999"
                            MaskType="Date" TargetControlID="txtStudent_Id"
                             ErrorTooltipEnabled="True">
```

**Updated:**

```
void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        return;

    // Do form stuff
}
```

Check this too  `EnableClientScript="True"` and  `Enabled="True"`

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server"  
                                Display="Dynamic" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtStudent_Id"
                                ID="rfvStudent_Id"
                                EnableClientScript="True"
                                Enabled="True"
                                ForeColor="Red"
                                ValidationGroup="VAlidation_Name"
                                ErrorMessage="Id is required">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: If any one enter any string characters , Then the OP got a error. But your code goods for the validation works buddy, not a fixing error message.

Comment: yeah you are right buddy..!! but in his case he said about the requiredfield not working but what you said is agreed. to enter only integers he can go with maskededitextender

Comment: So i added the `RequiredFieldValidator` , have a happy coding

Comment: Amarnath : `RequiredFieldValidator ` allow spaces,bcs space is a character  So this time he got a error. So i said about integer validation buddy

Comment: @RameshRajendran space is a character have you used MaskedEditextender? try that so that we can restrict the user entering characters. http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Comment: You're right, but he did not use `MaskedEditextender`. He have used just a `<asp:TextBox>`

Comment: @RameshRajendran it was my suggestion